# number.getValue() is undefined in Input

Tags: eclipse, jboss, workflow

I'm learning, how to create workflow in JBoss. 
I was using some youtube explanations, how to start it, but right now i have a problem with number.getValue() method. From what i understand, it should be imported from "Input", which i used. Any ideas?

I can't post images, so i give you a link with my problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0B72.jpg

I am thinking about creating getValue method by myself and import it for the sake of getValue, but i don't know where to start.

On the other hand - on this youtube video, code was correct, using getValue(), using same imports.

EDIT:
int value = Integer.valueOf(number.getValue()); <- getValue is undefined in Input

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have java library that includes .getValue() method.
Importing com.openKM.bean.form solved the problem.